# Unit testing conditional if/else statements w/ Mocha/Chai

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-statements, mocha.js, chai

Quick question, I can not find any documentation online in regards to testing a simple function with several if/else statements such as this fizzBuzz example...

```
module.exports =
function fizzBuzz(num) {
    for (let i; i <= num; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
            return 'FIZZBUZZ';
        } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
            return 'FIZZ';
        } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
            return 'BUZZ';
        } else {
            return 'Your number is' + i;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Chai...

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const fizzBuzz = require('../fizzBuzz.js');

describe.only('fizzBuzz', function () {
    describe('Smoke tests', function () {
        it('should exist', function () {
            expect(fizzBuzz).to.exist;
        })
        it('Should be a function', function() {
            expect(fizzBuzz).to.be.a('function');
        })
    })
})
```

What would be the syntax for checking each if/else statement? I would like to check to make sure on certain conditions, the function returns a string, and others returns a number. As well as when it returns a string, does it match which word should be returned. I am very new to Mocha/Chai.

Thank you in advance guys,

Brittany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
it('Pass param 5 should return \'BUZZ\'', function() {
    expect(fizzBuzz(5)).to.equal('BUZZ');
});
```